# IOS/Objective-C: Code to Make Round Image in Custom Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cell

The following code is working fine to make a square image round when placed in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

However, when I move the code to a custom cell, every time the tableview changes, it spreads the circle all the way across the table row into a horizontal blur.

[image]

```
 //following crops and rounds image

    CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);

    [self.iconView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
    self.iconView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.iconView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    self.iconView.layer.cornerRadius=20.0;
    self.iconView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 500, 50);

    //   [cell.iconView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
    //   cell.iconView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

In custom cell, I have been placing this code after the following:

```
self.iconview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
```

Does anyone know how I might fix this and still use a custom cell?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: your iconView frame is 500x50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is what "when I move the code to a custom cell" means - which you do not explain. But the problem is that `iconView` itself is being resized - it is being made wider. If you don't want that to happen, give it different constraints so that that doesn't happen.

Comment: Instead of having code in cellforrowatindexpath method of VC, move it to a new class, customCell.h/m.  Want to use the custom cell to give row some additional functionality.

Comment: Okay, but that changes nothing. `iconView` is a view. It is being stretched so the image is being stretched. Preventing that is up to you, by the way you set constraints on `iconView`.

Comment: commenting out the self.iconView.frame line seems to have stopped the problem

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for you to start the image context and get all the way down into CoreGraphics.

I accomplish this by:

```
imageView.image = myUIImage
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.bounds.size.width / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way to make rounded image in custom cell:

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageDemo.frame.size.width / 2;

imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

or follow this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-circular-image-calayer/)